# What does "CC" mean when it is labelling a capacitor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, diagram

I'm looking at a circuit diagram that doesn't list the capacitance for a couple of capacitors.

There's "C1", "C2" and "CC".

I can't imagine "CC" meaning constant current in this case, but I could be wrong.

When I searched the internet, the only thing I found was a "companion capacitor". If that is it, is there another name this goes by? There wasn't a lot of information.

[image: Circuit diagram]

[Source for the diagram.](https://www.hy-star.com.tw/Product/xlsemi/datasheet/XL2001%20datasheet.pdf)

Comment: I'm going with "Compensation Capacitor"  i.e. it's purpose is to allow the internal voltage regulator to maintain stability.

Comment: @KyleB should make that an answer, seems better than the ones so far.

Comment: It isn't a standard designator name so it could stand for Coca Cola, far as I know. Whoever made the circuit ought to explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe C**C** simply denotes the capacitor associated to V**C** (Internal Voltage Regulator Bypass Capacity), the same way C**IN** is associated to V**IN**.

The [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1134350/XLSEMI/XL2001.html) specifies `CC = 1 μF`.

[image]

Also, 105 specifies a capacitance of 1 μF. See [Capacitor Value Calculator](https://circuitdigest.com/calculators/capacitor-value-code-calculator).

Answer (score 1):

The capacitance is listed. It's 105 which is 1 \$\mu\$F.

That labeling convention is 2 digits and a multiplier, and the value in picoFarads. For 105 it would be 10 and 5 zeros, or 1,000,000 pF which is 1 \$\mu\$F.

The easiest way to learn it is to just memorize the most commonly seen multipliers.

105 = 1 \$\mu\$F
104 = 0.1 \$\mu\$F or 100 nF
103 = 0.01 \$\mu\$F or 10 nF
102 = 0.001 \$\mu\$F or 1 nF

Memorize those 4 and you'll be able to figure the value of almost any capacitor with that style of marking in your head.

As for the meaning of CC, the datasheet doesn't help much.

The VC pin is for a bypass capacitor for the internal regulator, CC doesn't make much sense, perhaps the were trying to match it with VC.

Answer (score 0):

"CC" would most likely be to identify a  "Coupling Capacitor", in this case coupling VC to VIN with a 1uF capacitor.